# Help making paragraph styles with a bulleted list and a paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, lists

So I've been tasked with flowing a word doc into InDesign to make a cook book. I've set up the master pages and layouts, and I have been struggling with getting the text to flow while having a bulleted list.

The document is typed out:
Title¶
• bullet¶
• bullet¶
• ...¶
Instruction paragraph.¶
Instruction paragraph.(page break)

So when I feed the text in it works for the title and first bullet, then the second one is instructions then it jumps to the next page and goes crazy.

My question is, is there a workaround for the hard returns in a bulleted list? In the instructions I can just change them to double soft returns, but that makes the list no longer bulleted.

---

By making styles in Word that match the paragraph styles in name (E.g. "Title" and "Title") and using the place options I'm able to keep the formatting the same. It's a little extra work but from here on out I can just have people type with the appropriate Word styles.

Now my problem is that the copy seems to want to skip one of the text boxes unless I manually click the little red arrow in the upper left corner of the box.

Comment: Might be faster to merely apply things with incorrect bullet lists, then go back and reset the lists.

Comment: Do you use a paragraph style specifically for the bullets? Can you elaborate on "goes crazy"? I've used bullets with paragraph returns with no problem in the past so I don't think you need to redo the doc...

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful here if you can edit them in the question